# Do you have to pickle scaler & ML model for deployment?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When training ML models with sklearn, I typically make use of the StandardScaler built into sklearn... first fitting the scaler to the training data, then transforming the training data... and finally using the same StandardScaler object to also transform the testing data via it’s previous fit parameters from the training dataset.

```
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

However, I’ve recently realized that I think any attempt to pickle and re-deploy the ML model in a different environment would also REQUIRE pickling the StandardScaler as well... otherwise new entry data would have no way to be transformed before being fed into the model. Is this a mistake on my part, or is there something I’m simply missing. Will I have to pickle BOTH the ML model and the StandardScaler every time I attempt to deploy them elsewhere?
It just seems odd that this was never mentioned in the Sci-kit learn [Model Persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) documentation.

```
joblib.dump(model, 'pickledModel.joblib')
joblib.dump(sc, 'pickledScaler.joblib')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what a [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) is used for:

```
from joblib import dump, load
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures

model = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('polyfeats', PolynomialFeatures()),
    ('ridge', Ridge())
])

dump(model, 'model.joblib')
model = load('model.joblib')
```

Now, you can easily save and load your pre-trained model as a single file.

Comment: But how do you ensure with pipeline that the same scaler is used for scaling during inference?

Comment: I guess it's your responsibility as a developer to ensure this. First, you create a model pipeline with a proper scaler, then you fit & save the pipeline on disk, after that you can load it anytime from disk and use it for inference.

Comment: Read more about the sklearn pipeline and understood your point.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for deployment you might also want to serialize your model to put it into database as bytes. With `joblib` it's a bit tricky, as you can only dump to file. Basically, you create some dummy container and dump it there.

```py
from io import BytesIO

import joblib

def serialize(obj) -> bytes:
    container = BytesIO()
    joblib.dump(obj, container)
    container.seek(0)

    serialized = container.read()
    return serialized


def deserialize(obj: bytes):
    container = BytesIO()
    container.write(obj)
    container.seek(0)

    deserialized = joblib.load(container)
    return deserialized
```